# Orders/Fulfilled Webhook Is Returning 404

Tags: node.js, shopify, webhooks, shopify-api-node

Fulfillment  request:

```
{"method":"POST","url":"MY_END_POINT","header":{"host":"MY_HOST","x-real-ip":"******","x-forwarded-for":"******","x-forwarded-proto":"https","connection":"upgrade","content-length":"9370","user-agent":"Shopify-Captain-Hook","accept":"*/*","accept-encoding":"gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3","content-type":"application/json","x-shopify-api-version":"2022-01","x-shopify-hmac-sha256":"FDd4emmeLmRf5HaK5CidHJJGYFEjhTBvhBf4TL2bvySifYE=","x-shopify-order-id":"4667509866751","x-shopify-shop-domain":"my-store.myshopify.com","x-shopify-test":"false","x-shopify-topic":"orders/fulfilled","x-shopify-webhook-id":"775hd36f-83k1-4810-928a-5eefb54527b4"}}
```

Fulfillment  response:

```
 {"status":404,"message":"Not Found","header":{}}
```

Create order fulfilment:

```
 "webhook": {
    "topic": "orders/fulfilled",
    "address": process.env.SHOPIFY_BASEURL+"init/shopify_webhookOrderFullFill",
    "format": "json",
   
     "private_metafield_namespaces": [
      "CLIENTID"
      ]
    }
```

My webhook json

https://"+shop+"/admin/api/2021-01/webhooks.json

Comment: what is MY_END_POINT and what is process.env.SHOPIFY_BASEURL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.post('init/shopify_webhookOrderFullFill',async (req,res) =>{
    console.log(req.request.body); // get all order fulfilment data
});
```